# jQuery's .unload fires on load in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to use jQuery's .unload() inside AngularJS:

**My Controller**

```
$(window).unload(someHandler());

var someHandler = function() {
  console.log('handled!');
};
```

**My View**

```
<section ng-controller="UnloadController">
</section>
```

The event is fired upon unload, but for some reason it is fired on load too. I am guessing this Angular messing something up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking it with the `()` when you pass the function in to the listener.

Try passing it in without invoking it.

```
$(window).unload(someHandler);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you! I'm glad that is all it was.